# A/B Test Between A Page And A Modal On Button Click

Tags: redirect, ab-testing, google-optimize

I currently have a lead gen site with a sitewide button in the header that opens a modal form for capturing leads.

I want to test a new version of the lead gen form. So I created another page with the new form on it, which can open on the button click (same sitewide button in header).

But before finalizing the change, I want to do a quick A/B test between the two. Here's the scenrio:

**Option 1**: Visitor 1 clicks on the button, modal opens just as before with the old lead gen form.
**Option 2**: VIsitor 2 clicks on the button, gets redirected to the new page with the new lead gen form.

Any suggstions on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Within your variation, you can add in global Javascript. I believe something like this should work to run Option 2 (you will need to update the selector and page):

```
var checkForElement = setInterval(function() {
    var button = document.querySelector('button'); // Change selector to your button
    if (button) {
        clearInterval(checkForElement);

        button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.location = '/new-page'; // Change to your page
        })
    }
}, 50);
```